# Identity Server 4 Authorization Flow

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, identityserver4

Identity server 4 and ASP.Net Core 3 noob here, what I'm trying to do is kinda simple: a client should do an HTTP Get request to a remote controller and retrieve some data after being authorized by the Identity Server.
I'm using a code flow as GrantType.

Identity Server services configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            // Identity server database
            string connectionString = Config.GetConnectionString("IdentityServerDatabase");

            services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerDatabaseContext>(config =>
            {
                config.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            });

            // Easy password for testing
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityServerDatabaseContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                // Identity User extension
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                });


            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "Server.Cookie";
                config.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
                config.LogoutPath = "/Home/Logout";
            });

            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
                opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12));

        }

//This is the IdentityServer jwt bearer, I'm using this because my IdentityServer is also an API that needs authorization, which I use for retrieving my users data:

services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", config =>
                {
                    // Identity Server authority
                    config.Authority = "https://localhost:44300/";

                    config.Audience = "IdentityAPI";
                });
```

This is the Identity Server configuration for accepted clients:

```
public class Configuration
    {

        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() =>
            new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes() =>
            new List<ApiScope> {
                new ApiScope("IdentityAPI"),
                new ApiScope("ClientGateway"),
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() =>
            new List<ApiResource> {
                new ApiResource("IdentityAPI")
                {
                    Scopes = { "IdentityAPI" }
                },
                new ApiResource("ClientGateway")
                {
                    Scopes = { "ClientGateway" }
                },
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
            new List<Client> {
                // Client for my IdentityServer
                new Client {
                    ClientId = "IdentityAPI",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret_IdentityAPI".ToSha256()) }, 

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

                    AllowedScopes = {
                        "IdentityAPI",
                        },
            };
            // My Client configuration, this client is trying to retrieve users data from the IdentityServer
            new Client {
                    ClientId = "ClientGateway",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret_ClientGateway".ToSha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,

                    RequirePkce = true,

                    // AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

                    // Necessary for authorization code flow type

                    // where to redirect to after login
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44400/signin-oidc" },
                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44400/Home/Index" },

                    RequireConsent = false,

                    AllowedScopes = {
                        "IdentityAPI",
                        "ClientGateway",
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    },
                },

    }
```

This is the client Startup:

```
public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Config;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment Env;

        public Startup(IConfiguration config, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            Config = config;
            Env = env;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(config =>
            {
                config.DefaultScheme = "Cookie";
                config.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookie")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", config =>
                {
                    config.SignInScheme = "Cookie";
                    config.ClientId = "ClientGateway";
                    config.ClientSecret = "secret_ClientGateway";
                    config.SaveTokens = true;
                    config.Authority = "https://localhost:44300/";
                    config.ResponseType = "code";
                    config.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/Home/Index";

                });

            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
   }
```

This is the Client Controller that is trying to authenticate and retrieve the data:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
    {

        private static readonly string IdentityAPIUrl = "https://localhost:44300";

        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public IdentityController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public static async Task<HttpClient> NewClientGatewayHttpClient(IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory)
        {
            var serverClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            var discoveryDocument = await serverClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(IdentityAPIUrl);

            var tokenResponse = await serverClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(
                new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
                {

                    Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
                    ClientId = "ClientGateway",
                    ClientSecret = "secret_ClientGateway",
                    Scope = "IdentityAPI",
                });

            var apiClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            return apiClient;

        }
        
        // I'm calling this function to retrieve users data from my IdentityServer
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("IDUsers")]
        public async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetIDUsers()
        {
            HttpClient apiClient = ModisIDController.NewClientGatewayHttpClient(_httpClientFactory).Result;
            
            // This response return a StatusCode: 200
            var response = await apiClient.GetAsync(IdentityAPIUrl + "/api/get/users");
            
            // In jsonResult I'm expecting my users data, but instead I'm receiving my view Login.cshtml as a string
            var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ApplicationUser>>(jsonResult);
        }
```

This is the IdentityServer function that the Client Controller is trying to call:

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    // Use this controller for Read API functions
    public class GetController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IdentityServerDatabaseContext _context;

        public GetController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IdentityServerDatabaseContext context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _context = context;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Users")]
        public IActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Users.ToList());
        }

    }
```

When ApiController tries to retrieve the data it gets correctly redirected to my Login view by the Identity Server, after login the user I get this output from my IdentityServer:

```
    info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
info: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Token request validation success, {
        "ClientId": "ClientGateway",
        "GrantType": "client_credentials",
        "Scopes": "IdentityAPI",
        "Raw": {
          "grant_type": "client_credentials",
          "scope": "IdentityAPI",
          "client_id": "ClientGateway",
          "client_secret": "***REDACTED***"
        }
      }
```

But the response that I retrieve in var content is HTML of the Login page and not the expected data. It seems like that the Identity Server is trying to redirect me again. I don't undestard why this happens because I'm using client credentials flow.

Comment: Edit: added Identity Server services configuration

Comment: What is the response that you're expecting? It doesn't seem like you're passing any cookies or tokens in your request which is probably why you're receiving the login page. The client probably gets a redirect that it follows and returns the index page that is at the resolved login page

Comment: Sorry for the long absence, I've edited my code. I'm expecting to retrieve my users data from AspNetUsers table in my database, which IdentityServer is using for storing user data for authorization purposes. I just need to retrieve that data, which is protected by a simple [Authorize] attribute.